# Convert varchar to date to use it into a where DB2

Tags: date, db2, compare, varchar

I am trying to compare a date and a varchar from a database. Imagine I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Sample (
    mydate VARCHAR(20),
    iddummy INTEGER
)
```

What I need to do is:

```
Select mydate, iddummy from Sample Where mydate > '01-30-2016';
```

However, as mydate is a varchar(20), it does not work. So I tried this way

```
SELECT date(to_date(mydate, '01-25-2016')) as newdate, iddummy 
FROM Sample
WHERE newdate < '01-30-2016'
```

Any ideas how to do that? I am getting Error Code -206

Comment: Any good reason why you need to store a data as a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: What format are your 'dates' in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-206" is because an alias ("AS newdate") defined in the SELECT clause is not yet visible in the WHERE clause; when parsing a SELECT statement, the clauses are taken in this order: FROM is first, then WHERE, then GROUP BY & HAVING, then SELECT, finally ORDER BY.
You would have to repeat the definition of newdate in the WHERE clause, or better: use a CTE:

```
WITH dt AS (
 SELECT date(to_date(mydate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) as newdate, iddummy 
 FROM Sample
)
SELECT * FROM dt WHERE newdate < '01-30-2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    SELECT mydate as newdate, iddummy 
FROM Sample
WHERE date(mydate)< '01-30-2016'
```

But this would throw you an "ERROR: An invalid datetime format was detected; that is, an invalid
string representation or value was specified" if your mydate contains a string which cannot be converted to date ex: '01-30-2016aa1232' etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
SELECT DATE(CHAR(trim(mydate),10) as newdate, iddummy 
FROM Sample
WHERE DATE(CHAR(trim(mydate),10) < '2016-01-30'
```

Answer (score -1):

Error code 206 states that "Column does not exist in any table of the SELECT". May be

SELECT mydate(to_date(mydate, '01-25-2016')) as newdate, iddummy 
FROM Sample
WHERE newdate < '01-30-2016'